# Button is not clickable at point XY, Other element would receive the click. In the selenium after the page is refreshed, argument headless added

Tags: python, selenium

I see many asks on the Stack Overflow with titles like mine, but my code is running well without any error in GUI mode, without GUI I can click on the button, but after the page refresh, I have an error.

Comment: which lines causes that issue ? Can you share some relevant info ? like code trials, error stack trace

Comment: @cruisepandey
code is simple, just inputs some text into text fields and click on the button, but after page refresh button is not clickable
`selenium.common.exceptions.ElementClickInterceptedException: Message: element click intercepted: Element <button id="submit" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">...</button> is not clickable at point (572, 581). Other element would receive the click: <footer>...</footer>
  (Session info: headless chrome=91.0.4472.124)`

Comment: okay, where is this element present in the UI ? looks like a submit button. Can you share URL or HTML  ?

Comment: @cruisepandey
https://demoqa.com/automation-practice-form

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you should set correct screen size for the headless mode.
Try this:

```
options.add_argument("window-size=1920x1080")
```

or this

```
options.add_argument("window-size=1920,1080")
```

Comment: `options.add_argument (" window-size = 1920x1080 ")` worked, thanks

Comment: Both options work.
I mean both from the first code example.
The "--start-maximized" does not work.